# Excel return whole row when column cell matches value using formula only

Tags: excel

i want return whole row when cell matches value.
Only using excel formulas no VBA.
Is there any way ?

[Input image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wo33p.jpg)

I want to find 900 in green column ...when it found, it will write in sheet2 with found value with its corresponding whole row.

in this case i found three 9000 ...so i want output like: in following image

[Ouput image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/525yJ.jpg)

I want to use only excel formulas 
Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your data that you want to extract is in range A1:E4, you can use this.

Note: Enter as an array, with <kbd>CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER</kbd>

`=INDEX(A$1:A$4,SMALL(IF($B$1:$B$4=900,ROW(B$1:B$4)-ROW(B$1)+1),ROWS(B$1:B1)))`

Adjust the range as necessary. You can drag this formula right and down.  Also, wrap `IfError([formula],"")` to hide when it can't find anything.

[image]